# как архивировать директорию с файлами в zip архив с помощью кода?

Tags: java, zip, архивация

Это директория `File file = new File("D:/new");`

Comment: Например можно через запуск архиватора сделать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можно по конкретнее ?

Comment: Запускаете архиватор такой вот командой "7z a out D:\Temp\*" и получаете архив указанного каталога.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов мне нужно код написать для этой программы

Comment: Пишите код запуска сторонней программы, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можете отправить похожий код?

Comment: Могу на Питоне, например. А на java я не пишу.

Comment: Внешняя команда только для winrar-а. Zip есть прямо в жабу встроенный.

Answer (score 4):

Возможно сделать через реализацию интерфейса FileVisitor, что поможет обойти всё дерево вызывая метод для упаковки конкретного файла и добавление упакованного  файла в общий архив. 
На странице https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html есть конкретный пример реализации и использования

Пакет https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html - содержит необходимые классы и методы для упаковки файла.

Comment: можно по конкретнее ?